# Mysql, PHP, searching for multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to search a table for specific words.

Say I have a list of words: printer,network,wireless,urgent

I only want to return those rows where all of these words are in it.

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE concat(subject,body) REGEXP "printer|network|wireless|urgent"
```

will return any row with any one of these words.  How can I make it so that it will only return those rows where all of these words are in it.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the number of words that have to appear fixed or variable?

Comment: a variable preferably.

Comment: You could do `LIKE '%word1%' AND LIKE '%word2%' AND ...`, though the performance won't be great. If you are implementing keyword searching generally, you may wish to look into text-index base systems, such as Zend Lucene (that's PHP based, there are others if you don't mind using other languages).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first is the rather obvious approach. Let's say you have all the words that need to appear in an array called $necessaryWords:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ...'; // and so on
$sql .= ' WHERE 1';

foreach ($necessaryWords as $word)
    $sql .= ' AND concat(subject,body) LIKE "%' . $word . '%"'; //Quotes around string
```

However, using `%foo%` is rather slow, as no indexes can be used, so this query might cause performance issues with huge tables and/or a high number of necessary words.

The other approach would be a `FULLTEXT` index on `subject` and `body`. You could the use the fulltext `MATCH IN BOOLEAN MODE` like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ...'; // and so on
$sql .= ' WHERE MATCH(subject,body) AGAINST("';

foreach ($necessaryWords as $word)
    $sql .= ' +' . $word;
$sql .= '")';
```

<s>Note that your table must use `MyISAM` in order to use `FULLTEXT` indexes.</s> UPDATE: [As of MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html), `InnoDB` supports `FULLTEXT` indexes as well. I guess this could be the better choice performance wise. Further documentation on the fulltext in boolean mode can be found in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: @DobotJr: For both curiosity and possible future visitants of this page: Which version did you choose, and why?

Answer (score 1):

not the best way, but:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE
concat(subject,body) REGEXP "printer" AND
concat(subject,body) REGEXP "network" AND
concat(subject,body) REGEXP "wireless" AND
concat(subject,body) REGEXP "urgent"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE
   concat(subject,body) LIKE "%printer%" AND
   concat(subject,body) LIKE "%network%" AND
   concat(subject,body) LIKE "%wireless%" AND
   concat(subject,body) LIKE "%urgent%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would work with MySQL regex engine but the regex (using lookarounds) below can achieve what you are looking for. Will find the words of interest irrespective of the order in which they occur:

```
^(?=.*printer)(?=.*network)(?=.*wireless)(?=.*urgent).*$
```

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/XcVz5xMZcb

Some regex lookaround examples here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer, just because I thought of it when I looked at your question. I do not know whether it would be faster than the other answers (most likely no):

```
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE subject LIKE "%printer%" OR body LIKE "%printer%")
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE subject LIKE "%network%" OR body LIKE "%network%")
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE subject LIKE "%wireless%" OR body LIKE "%wireless%")
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE subject LIKE "%urgent%" OR body LIKE "%urgent%")
```

UPDATE:
This is wrong

Comment: This will return all rows that contain either of the words.